# Spring 4.3.1 static resource configuration error

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 4.3.1+java 8 and try to configure project according to that I had done all configuration but while configuring static resource in servlet-context.xml I got compilation error as follows :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues.get(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.MvcNamespaceUtils.getContentNegotiationManager(MvcNamespaceUtils.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.ResourcesBeanDefinitionParser.registerResourceHandler(ResourcesBeanDefinitionParser.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.ResourcesBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ResourcesBeanDefinitionParser.java:94)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.namespaces.DelegatingNamespaceHandlerResolver$ElementTrackingNamespaceHandler.parse(DelegatingNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1427)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$ErrorSuppressingBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeansConfig.java:1400)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$ToolingFriendlyBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:1330)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:494)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$2.registerBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:402)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$2.loadBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:388)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$3.call(BeansConfig.java:445)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$3.call(BeansConfig.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd ">


    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="mkcl.os.apps" />

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <beans:property name="paramName" value="lang" />
        </beans:bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>     

</beans:beans>
```

I had tried many ways and done lot of google but none of them worked.

pom.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>mkcl.os</groupId>
 <artifactId>MKCLTemplateProject</artifactId>
 <name>MKCLTemplateProject</name>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <properties>
  <java-version>1.8</java-version>
  <org.springframework-version>4.3.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
  <jackson.library>2.7.5</jackson.library>
  <org.aspectj-version>1.8.9</org.aspectj-version>
  <org.slf4j-version>1.7.21</org.slf4j-version>
  <!-- Default Character encoding -->
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>utf8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 </properties>
 <dependencies>
  <!-- Spring -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
   <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
   <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
   <version>2.9.0</version>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
   <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
   <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
  </dependency>


  <!--AspectJ and aop START -->

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
   <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
   <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
  </dependency>


  <!-- Jackson -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
   <version>1.9.13</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
   <version>1.9.13</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- EXCEL SHEET START -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
   <version>3.6</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
     <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
     <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Property Utils API START -->


  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-beanutils-core</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.0</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
     <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
   <version>2.3</version>
  </dependency>


  <!-- Property Utils API END EXCEL SHEET END -->

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>mkcl.os</groupId>
   <artifactId>Person</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.44.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>mkcl.os</groupId>
   <artifactId>LocalDALWOH</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.13.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
     <groupId>antlr</groupId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Logging -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
   <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
   <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
   <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
   <!-- <scope>runtime</scope> -->
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.17</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
     <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
     <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
     <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
     <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>

  <!-- @Inject -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
   <version>1</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Servlet -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.2</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Test -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>4.12</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <!-- sitemesh 3.0 -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.sitemesh</groupId>
      <artifactId>sitemesh</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
  </dependency>


  <!-- apacheds -->

  <!-- DAL -->

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb-parent</artifactId>
   <version>1.9.2.RELEASE</version>
   <type>pom</type>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
   <!-- <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
     <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions> -->
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.26</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>mkcl.os</groupId>
   <artifactId>MKCLModel</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.48.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
   <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Cache Dependencies Ehcache Web -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
   <artifactId>ehcache-web</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.4</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <!-- spring cache -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.code.simple-spring-memcached</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cache</artifactId>
   <version>3.6.0</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Spymemcached Cache -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.code.simple-spring-memcached</groupId>
   <artifactId>spymemcached-provider</artifactId>
   <version>3.6.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- EhCache -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>mkcl.os</groupId>
   <artifactId>Cache</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.15.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>mkcl.os</groupId>
   <artifactId>MKCLTemplateProjectSupport</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.28.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
   <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
   <version>1.7</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
     <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
     <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <!-- For using CSPRNG to generate salt key -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>mkcl.os</groupId>
   <artifactId>NotificationService</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.7.RELEASE</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
     <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
     <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>mkcl.os</groupId>
   <artifactId>LoginAccountBL</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.11.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>mkcl.os</groupId>
   <artifactId>DAL</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.35.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.external</groupId>
   <artifactId>antlr-repackaged</artifactId>
   <version>3.1-b30</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- For Classloader leak protection -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>se.jiderhamn</groupId>
   <artifactId>classloader-leak-prevention</artifactId>
   <version>1.8.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>mkcl.os</groupId>
   <artifactId>MKCLSecurity</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.4</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>mkcl.os</groupId>
   <artifactId>LoginAccountModel</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.16</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>mkcl.os</groupId>
   <artifactId>MenuManagement</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.53</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
     <additionalProjectnatures>
      <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
     </additionalProjectnatures>
     <additionalBuildcommands>
      <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
     </additionalBuildcommands>
     <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
     <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>

    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.6</source>
     <target>1.6</target>
     <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
     <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
     <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
     <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

 <repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>spy</id>
   <name>Spy Repository</name>
   <layout>default</layout>
   <url>http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/</url>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </repository>

 </repositories>

</project>
```

Comment: Looks like incompatible Versions of `spring-web-mvc` and `spring-beans`. Can you Show your pom.xml

Comment: can you try to clean and rebuild your Project? and take a look into your Server classpath, if you have spring jar's with Version lower than 4 in your classpath

Comment: already I had done this lot of time and also checked all jars.

Comment: You have also checked the lib Directory?

Comment: yes checked and versions are spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE, spring-webmvc-4.3.1.RELEASE

Comment: Also in the tomcat/lib (i guess you run your app in tomcat)

Comment: I had checked that if I had commented <annotation-driven /> then compile time error resolved but runtime it not worked. Error is occured at mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

Comment: any error message?

Comment: it having compile time error and if I removed annotation driven then it having runtime error not displaying any page bt displayed only blank page.

Comment: What is the compile time error?

Comment: Resolved my issue I just changed order of annotation-driven and resources tag.. By the way thanx for help